# Issue with brackets in affiliate-urls

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-encoding

I am using the Zanox affiliate program.

My url has the following structure:

```
ad.zanox.com/ppc/?foo&zpar0=[[bar]]
```

While i link from my native iOS-application and it will open the Safari the square double brackets "[[]]" are encoded into "%5B%5B%5D%5D" so that my link from above at Safari now looks like:

```
ad.zanox.com/ppc/?foo&zpar0=%5B%5Bbar%5D%5D
```

Objective-C:

```
_postUrl = @"ad.zanox.com/ppc/?foo&zpar0=[[bar]]";

NSString *button = [self htmlButtonWithTitle:@"Affiliate-Link" andURL:_postUrl];
```

Is there any possibility to keep the square double brackets?

My only workaround now is to use bit.ly for the affiliate link. So far this only affects Zanox platform for me. It's an extra (unwanted) redirect, but better than nothing. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking... The encoded URL does not work? Or you don't know how to encode it?

Comment: I am using the String ad.zanox.com/ppc/?foo&zpar0=[[bar]] and want to have the same look in my Safari browser - but Safari will transform in into ad.zanox.com/ppc/?foo&zpar0=%5B%5Bbar%5D%5D by itself.

My aim is to keep the square double brackets in Safari also.

Comment: Brackets are invalid in the URL, I don't think you can do that...